# How can I deploy AWS SageMaker Linear Learner Model in a Local Environment

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a AWS SageMaker Model using the in-built Linear Learner algorithm. I can download the trained model artifacts (model.tar.gz) from S3.

How can I deploy the model in an local environment which is independent of AWS, so I can make predictions inferences calls without internet access?

Answer (score 0):

Matx, there is no local mode for built-in algorithms. However, you can programmatically load mxnet module with model weights and use it to make predictions. Check https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=827236&#827236 for code example.

Comment: Hi Yuri, What is mxnet module and how is it related the Linear Learner inbuilt algorithm? I am new to SageMaker and Machine Learning. Many Thanks.

Comment: By mxnet module I mean `mxnet.module.Module` class. It can load a model from files saved by SageMaker Linear Learner. See also https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/module/module.html#mxnet.module.Module

Comment: Hi Yury, thanks for your help. I got as far as "mod = mx.module.Module.load("mx-mod", 0)", but get an error on this line: "You created Module with Module(..., label_names=['softmax_label']) but input with name 'softmax_label' is not found in symbol.list_arguments(). Did you mean one of:
 data
 out_label"

Comment: Matx, try to pass `label_names=["out_label"]` as the last parameter to `Module.load`.